# Maintaining UIBezierPath above CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, drawrect, cashapelayer

I have a circle added to `CAShapeLayer` and a line with `UIBeizerPath`. I want to maintain the position of line to be above circle. Basically in `drawRect`, position of the items will be maintained one after the other. So, I call `drawCircle()` first and invoke `drawLine()` expecting that line has to be on top of the circle. Here is my code.

```
class DrawView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        drawCircle()
        drawLine()
    }
    
    private func drawCircle() {
        if let sublayers = layer.sublayers {
            for layer in sublayers where layer.name == "Circle" {
                layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
        }
        
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: 400),
                                      radius: 20.0,
                                      startAngle: 0,
                                      endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2),
                                      clockwise: true)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.name = "Circle"
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
            
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
    
    private func drawLine() {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x:bounds.midX, y:0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: 400))
        path.close()
        
        UIColor.blue.set()
        path.lineWidth = 20.0
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

and below is the result

[image]

But, adding the line to another `CAShapeLayer` gives the expected result, adds the line on top of circle. How can I bring the line on top of circle without adding the line to a `CAShapeLayer`.

Comment: You can also reconsider drawing layers and create 2 views, and you can modify the `customView.layer.zPosition` for each view. For example, create a circle view, with clear background and red border, and then another view, which is 20 width and 400 height, add them both to the DrawView as subviews.

Comment: See the (second) answer I gave you to your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75800357/scale-uiview-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `render` the circle layer in the current graphics context:

```
shapeLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
// instead of
// layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

This essentially "draws" the layer in the same way that `UIBezierPath.stroke` draws things. So the things that are drawn first appear "below" the things that are drawn later.

`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` will not return nil here because you are calling this from `draw`.

That said, I would recommend that you either do everything with layers (and update the layers in `layoutSubviews`) or *only* draw things in `draw`. Stick to one of them. Mixing the two makes the code messier, in my opinion.