# scaling buttons grid with CGAffineTransform goes wrong

Tags: swift, scrollview, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to make buttons grid that will be scale up and down with pinching the scrollview , I am inspired by [Scale UIView elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75800357/scale-uiview-elements/75899517#75899517) and the answer by donmag.
the problem is that the buttons comes out of the scrollview, its showing on the main view as well but I want it inside the scrollview and when I zoom in and out they do not stay together like the grid , they separate or go together.
dose anyone knows how to fix these two problem.i know I should ask just one question at time but these are some how in the same category ,sorry and thanks for helping. .you can run the code , just give ComplexVC to a view controller.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit






class DrawZoomBaseVC: UIViewController {
    
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    
    // this will be a plain, clear UIView that we will use
    //  as the viewForZooming
    let zoomView = UIView()
    
    // this will be placed *behind* the scrollView
    //  in our subclasses, we'll set it to either
    //      Simple or Complex
    //  and we'll set its zoomScale and contentOffset
    //  to match the scrollView
    var drawView: UIView!
    
    // a label to put at the top to show the current zoomScale
    let infoLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.text = "\n\n\n"
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        
        [infoLabel, drawView, scrollView].forEach { v in
            v!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v!)
        }
        zoomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(zoomView)
        
        drawView.backgroundColor = .black
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .clear
        zoomView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // info label at the top
            infoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            infoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            infoLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            zoomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            zoomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            zoomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            zoomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            drawView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            drawView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            drawView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            drawView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            ])
        
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 60.0
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.1
        scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
        
        scrollView.indicatorStyle = .white
        
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
        infoLabel.isHidden = false
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        // if we're using the ComplexDrawScaledView
        //  we *get* its size that was determined by
        //  it laying out its elements in its commonInit()
        
      
            if let dv = drawView as? ComplexDrawScaledView {
                zoomView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: dv.virtualSize.width).isActive = true
                zoomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: dv.virtualSize.height).isActive = true
        }
        
        // let auto-layout size the view before we update the info label
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.updateInfoLabel()
        }
    }
    
    func updateInfoLabel() {
        infoLabel.text = String(format: "\nzoomView size: (%0.0f, %0.0f)\nzoomScale: %0.3f\n", zoomView.frame.width, zoomView.frame.height, scrollView.zoomScale)
    }
    
}

extension DrawZoomBaseVC: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      
            if let dv = drawView as? ComplexDrawScaledView {
                dv.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        }
    }
    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        updateInfoLabel()
      
            if let dv = drawView as? ComplexDrawScaledView {
                dv.zoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale
        }
    }
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return zoomView
    }
}



class ComplexVC: DrawZoomBaseVC {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        drawView = ComplexDrawScaledView()
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
}



class ComplexDrawScaledView: UIView {
    
    public var virtualSize: CGSize = .zero
    
    public var zoomScale: CGFloat = 1.0 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    public var contentOffset: CGPoint = .zero { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    
    private let nCols: Int = 32
    private let nRows: Int = 128
    private let colWidth: CGFloat = 120.0
    private let rowHeight: CGFloat = 80.0
    private let colSpacing: CGFloat = -2.0
    private let rowSpacing: CGFloat = -2.0
    
    private let buttonInset: CGSize = .init(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
    
    private var buttons: [UIButton] = []
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        var r: CGRect = .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: colWidth, height: rowHeight)
        for _ in 0..<nRows {
            for _ in 0..<nCols {
                let button = UIButton(type: .system)
                button.frame = r.insetBy(dx: buttonInset.width, dy: buttonInset.height)
                button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                // Set button border properties
                button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
                button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

                buttons.append(button)
                addSubview(button)
                r.origin.x += colWidth + colSpacing
            }
            r.origin.x = 0.0
            r.origin.y += rowHeight + rowSpacing
            
        }
        
        // Set virtual size based on button layout
        let w: CGFloat = buttons.compactMap({ $0.frame.maxX }).max() ?? 0
        let h: CGFloat = buttons.compactMap({ $0.frame.maxY }).max() ?? 0
        virtualSize = CGSize(width: w, height: h)
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let tr = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -contentOffset.x, y: -contentOffset.y)
            .scaledBy(x: zoomScale, y: zoomScale)
        
        buttons.forEach { button in
            button.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            button.transform = tr
        }
    }
    
    @objc private func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Button tapped")
        // Handle button tap if needed
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to run into several issues... 1) applying a scale transform to a view (a `UIButton` is a view) scales *from the center* ... applying a scale transform to a path scales from top-left, *including* the origin. 2) using the approach you referenced, your buttons will be *behind* the scroll view and you won't be able to tap them. 3) you're adding the buttons as subviews, so trying to manage anything in `draw()` doesn't make sense. 4) adding 4096 buttons will be a very heavy and resource intensive approach.

Comment: If you ***really*** need 4096 buttons, you *should* be able to use a "normal" scroll view approach.

Comment: The master himself thank you so much for taking your time to answer my stupid questions.actually several months ago you told me to take this approach. If you remember, I am trying to make a piano roll,I need the grid but under that I need buttons or some how be able to have sound of the row , each row is a note, I need just 128 buttons in row and it must stretch as long as the end column to be able to have the sound of the row for entire time.in this example I just wanted to make it just like my grid to prove my theory but it goes all over the place.

Comment: I made the hole thing with normal scrollview but I couldn’t zoom enough so you told me to take this approach.  and I have another scrollview on the left side of this and it must have 128 buttons in it like piano,I just tried to make two scrollview with the grid to try if it’s possible but I have another problem.the left scrollview doesn’t show the content , if please you can check it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77518222/two-scrollviews-side-by-side-one-does-not-show-the-content. So what do you think how should I make this hole mess right ?

Comment: Should I use buttons under the grid or find something els . Should I even use buttons on the left scrollview?but if with this approach I can’t tap the buttons .I can’t even use them like this for the left side . And if I use the grid like this for this side and use normal scrollview for the left side buttons how should I Mach the zoom ,the zoom scale can be same but in this way it get much bigger than normal way?

Comment: I just updated this example: https://github.com/DonMag/VirtualZoom with a "Musical Notes" grid view... that shows how to respond to taps without using `UIButton`s ... tapping in any grid "cell" will toggle a Musical Note on/off. For this task - along with your other "side-by-side" question - you ***really*** need to start simple and learn how these things work. You're trying to "write a novel" before you've even learned the alphabet. **Study the example code** until you understand it.

Comment: thank you so much brother.i will study your code.i couldn't open it jet but I will find a solution.i have an old Mac and Xcode 10.1, your code is on higher version and I Cann't install higher version.you are absolutely right I am trying to write a novel but I don't know the alphabet.how did you learn all of this?which books should I read? I study all of the stuff on apple developer and youtube tutorials on for example scrollview but nobody mentions the things you do with scrollview.how you come up with this stuff ? you are a true master with knowledge and great heart.

Comment: I've been writing code for over 30 years, so I couldn't tell you "which books" you should read. **Start Simple**. Work on a single task at a time. **Learn** what you're trying to do -- write the code, as opposed to copy/pasting.

Comment: @DonMag everting is working well.the only problem I have is , the way that looks ,the grid get bigger with zoom but I need it like Garage band Pianorolle that when I pinch vertical the height of grid linen changes and when horizontal the width of the grid get bigger . I had it in my old code like every time I pinch the width or Height changed but I had problems with layering and couldn’t get big enough so you suggested this method,with this get big but doesn’t look right, I tried so many thing but i can’t make it work. Do you have any idea how to make this work?please ?

Comment: A `UIScrollView` only has a single `scale` factor. If you want UI elements that scale  horizontally and vertically *independent of each other*, you will almost certainly not want to be using that approach.